# Retrieving crash-dump from Windows Phone 8 devices

Tags: windows-phone-8, crash-dumps

Is there a way to get crash-dumps out of Windows Phone 8 during development time? I am after a file that is dumped similarly to when a normal Win32 app crashes. Or similar to what is saved on iOS devices at crash to be investigated at a later point.

My question is specifically about somehow retrieving this (or similar) file/info from the phone after a crash without me having to do anything in my code e.g. manually writing the stack trace to a file from an unhandled exception.

I am aware the option of getting "live" crash reports from a beta-submitted app but that is not what I am after.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a crash-dump you can access. At least not on WP8. I can't say about 8.1, but I doubt it. Personally, I am using a custom LittleWatson class from this blog post:

http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/adventures-in-unhandled-exception-handling-for-xnasilverlight/

Scroll down to 'Out of the box Silverlight" and grab the class. It is already rigged with an email task for sending the crash report if that comes in handy.

This will at least save you the time of writing a crash report saver manually.

Comment: I have managed to get this information from the Windows Phone team at Microsoft: what I am looking for is not possible. I have provided them feedback on what (in my opinion not that uncommon) situation it might put some developers. I hope they will consider doing something about it. In the meantime you have options similar along the lines of what @ertay-shashko suggested, or upload your app for beta testing and get the crash report from the dashboard of your developer account.

Answer (score 4):

You can grab them on WP 8.1 by browsing to ThisPC/Windows Phone/Phone/Documents/Debug while the phone is connected.

Ref: http://mtaulty.com/2015/02/19/m_15734/

Answer (score 2):

1. [Developer unlock your device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx).
2. Turn on "Settings/feedback/Save info" option in the phone settings
3. Wait for crash
4. Connect the phone with USB and navigate to \Phone\Documents\Debug\yourApp.dmp
5. [Here is an article about analyzing it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2015/03/30/how-to-make-use-of-crash-dumps-available-on-the-store-dev-portal.aspx).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get crash dumps from Windows Dev Center once you uploaded your app to Microsoft Beta - which you really should do before releasing it live. The app is available 2 hours after you upload it but the crash dumps will be available 3 days later.

No need to say you need to save your PDB files.