# Windows Phone 8.1 app crashes when downloaded from store

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I'm dealing with a strange issue that's been giving me headaches for a long time.

I've got a Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) app, whose first version I published a couple of years ago. Over the last few months, I've been working on a major update which includes augmented reality as the most prominent feature.

Obviously, the app needs to make use of the camera preview, and that's where trouble starts. I've read discussions in other threads about problems with the camera API, but I didn't find a definite solution.

Before submitting the update, I performed extensive tests on my Lumia 620 and all worked fine. But if the app is downloaded from the store, it crashes and the camera picture goes green as soon as the camera preview starts. It is the very same app package and all required capabilites have been declared.

So basically I can't tell if my app works or not, unless I submit it to the store.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**: After several hidden-app submissions, I've narrowed down the cause of the crash to the following block of code:

```
RandomAccessStreamReference rasr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png"));
var streamWithContent = await rasr.OpenReadAsync();
```

The last of the above lines causes the app to terminate. The same code works fine when the app is deployed from VS.
Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a link to the store? does the app crash on 8.1 or Win10 mobile? or on both?

Comment: Here is the link to the store: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/precise-sat-finder/9wzdncrcwdqv
I have removed the problematic feature from the current package.

It definitely crashes on my Lumia 620 (WP 8.1), and all reports I've received so far are from 8.1 users. I don't know if it also crashes on Win10.

Comment: get the dumps of the crashes and analyze them: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephe/2015/03/30/how-to-use-windows-or-windows-phone-store-app-crash-dumps-found-on-your-dev-portal/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/30894250/1466046 https://mtaulty.com/2015/02/19/m_15734/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I haven't been able to extract any useful info yet. There is no "Export trace" button in the Dashboard, nor does the phone create a dump file after the crash.

Comment: have you changed the setting on the phone to generate the dumps on the phone?

Comment: Yes, I've done that. Anyway, I'm wondering why an app would work when deployed from VS, but crash when downloaded from the store...

Comment: do you deploy the debug build from VS? maybe this is the issue, that the debug works, but the Release crashes

Comment: Both the debug and the release builds work fine when deployed from VS. The store package crashes.

Comment: Can you view the [Health report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/health-report?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Dashboard? Change the default filter from 72 hours to last 30 days and check the crash info so you can view stack trace to debug. And you can submit your update as hidden app only the one who have promo code can download it then you can test if it works. If it works, you could change its availability as public app.

Comment: It looks like the green-screen crash isn't reported in the dashboard. Your suggestion about the hidden app submission is a sensible one, as there seems to be no other way. But it is extremely impractical to debug, if one has to submit a package to the store for every code modification that could break the app for some unpredictable reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is now resolved. The cause of the crashes was the asset file. This file is a scaled version of the app tile, which is created automatically by Visual Studio. Using this file is allowed when the app is deployed from VS, but not in the store.